# How can I duplicate a row and change a single value, without listing all column names?

Tags: sql-server, query

I'm working on a legacy system, so I can't change the architecture of this. The system has the concept of templates. These are used to accompany invitations, format reports, and other stuff like this. A choice was made a couple of decades ago that all the different template types should have their own table. So now I have 1 table with the template name, id and other metadata, and 25 tables with different contents, all with their own schema. They all have two fields in common, `ID` and `TemplateID`, the first is a identity field that is never used for anything, the second references the table with name and metadata.

The owner has decided they want to be able to clone templates. They often use mostly the same template for several years in a row. So what I'm after is a generic solution to - for 25 separate tables - duplicate a row, and change the `TemplateID` of the duplicated row to a new ID corresponding to a new entry in the metadata table. I have found a couple of clone-row solutions, but they all seem to expect that the ID or field you want to change is the primary key/identity column. And I could of course write 25 different `insert into <table> select col1, col2, col3, col4, <new TemplateID>, col6, col7` statements but that irks me in ways I can't explain.

Anyone have a more elegant solution to the problem? I'm running sql-server, and I'm currently stuck in 2008 compatibility mode :(, nothing I can do with that for now.

Comment: How _elegant_ of a solution are you looking for?  Would you be satisfied with 25 inserts if you **did not** have to specify the actual columns for the individual tables?

Comment: "Elegance" is relative. TBH seems you seek "easy". The short answer is no - there is no alternative in a tsql statement. The longer - and perhaps inelegant but inefficient approach - is to use the lazy form of `insert tbl select * from tba` and then update the the newly inserted row as needed. Many assumptions built into that approach so it may not work with your schema. Alternatively, you write code to write your sql statements based on the meta-data of your table. You might spend far more time trying to do that than writing the few you need manually.

Comment: And generally speaking, a problematic schema will force the use of tsql that one might consider inelegant.